# how to deploy rule using code in wso2 brs

Tags: wso2

I am able to deploy rules from UI in wso2 brs, and I can access the rules from java client. 
But the rule configure UI is not friendly to end users. So we need to build our own rule configure UI. 
Then how can we deploy the rules defined in our system by using code to deploy to brs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After strugling for few month, I am able to do that now.
Even there is no API to do that, I simulate the browser operation, and upload rules to WSO2 BRS.